# Why need DevKit

Tags: ruby

When I tried to setup my debug environment for Ruby.
I have to get gem package `debug_base` and `debug_ide` from repository. 'gem install xxx' command will download packages and using `DevKit` to compile the package. I was thinking why **weren't** these gem package compiled in advance? So we don't need `DevKit` to do build job when installing them. Is there any other purpose for `DevKit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some packages/gems need to be compiled in advance to work because they use native extensions.

This is done automatically by ruby gem when you use the gem command.

Devkit is:

> The RubyInstaller Development Kit is a toolkit that makes it easy to build and use native C/C++ extensions such as RDiscount and RedCloth for Ruby on Windows

Comment: Sorry for the typo. why weren't these gem package compiled in advance.Please review my edit.

Comment: Because compilation depends on the computer. Gems can compile differently based on your computer. They compile differently on windows, mac and linux for example. Or two users with windows could have different librairies installed and the gem will compile differently.